# elasticsearch cross fields query alternative for fuzziness?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have a cross-fields query, and I understand already that you cant use fuzziness with cross-fields queries, but I dont understand the alternative...

this is my simple query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "John Legend",
            "fields": [
              "fname^-4.0",
              "lname^-1.0",
              "city^-1.0",
            ],
            "type": "cross_fields",
            "lenient": "true",
            "operator": "AND"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": "1"
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20
}
```

I want to be able to find:

1. John Legend
2. Joh
3. John Lege

is that possible?

Comment: you can, with a copy_to technique ( you copy all your searchable field in one field ) then use a match query on it with fuzziness. But you will lose the ability to boost fname over lname. But you can give it a try and see if the result is correct for you.